# Intel AX200 not "claimed" and random purple screening when cursor is in the bottom left corner of the screen

Tags: networking, 20.04

I'm new to this but I've run out of places to ask for help.

Desktop Specs (for future reference):

- Ryzen 9 3950X
- ASUS ROG Crosshair VIII Hero (with WiFi)
- 64 GB Corsair Vengence Pro RGB (2 x 32 GB)
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 240 (temp card because I'm waiting on the RTX 3000 to drop soon)
- Corsair AX 850W PSU
- Kraken Z73 AIO Cooler
- Samsung Evo 970 1 TB NVMe

I am Dual-Booting this desktop with 750 GB going to Windows and 250 GB going to Ubuntu 20.04

`uname -a` yields `Linux omega 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I've reached multiple problems in trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my desktop.
The first problem is that Ubuntu doesn't "claim" my integrated WiFi card on the motherboard.
Running `lshw -C network` yields:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: d4:5d:64:d2:1c:8c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8125a-3_0.0.1 08/24/19 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:61 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7810000-f781ffff memory:f7820000-f7823fff memory:f7800000-f780ffff memory:f7830000-f789ffff memory:f78a0000-f78bbfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: d4:5d:64:d2:1c:8b
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=0. 6-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:39 memory:f7700000-f771ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:f7720000-f7723fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7600000-f7603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:4
       logical name: wlxe84e060a4643
       serial: e8:4e:06:0a:46:43
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=5.4.0-26-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.128 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I am currently using a USB Dongle for WiFi, but I'd much rather the free USB port. I've tried installing the right driver for the Intel WiFi and put it into `/lib/firmware` but nothing has changed

Second error is on terms of glitches with the UI. For some reason, if I drag my cursor to the very bottom left of my screen to the point where my cursor seems gone, my system "purple screens" but a very light purple color. I haven't found what is the source of this error but my money is on the graphics card.

I'm a beginner to this Linux stuff and have tried a lot of things on the web, and I would really like to solve both of these issues. Please let me know if I have to run anything more on my desktop to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright turns out that Windows is really greedy. By default Windows 10 has Fast Boot active, meaning that it hoards the builtin Wi-Fi card for itself, and doesn't let Ubuntu have it. If you [turn off fast boot](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) then Ubuntu will be able to register the Intel AX 200 card that is builtin the ASUS ROG Crosshair VIII Hero (Wi-Fi) board all fine and dandy.

I'm also convinced that my graphical error is a limitation of my NVIDIA GeForce GT 240 GPU. It only has 1 GB of VRAM and I assume that that is causing the purple screens for me.

TL;DR if you want to fix the Wi-Fi issue and you have Windows 10 installed on the same machine, consider [turning off fast boot](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup).