# wifi is not catching in my DELL latitude 3420 laptop

Tags: kernel

I have installed ubuntu 22.04 in my DELL latitude 3420 laptop. My wifi card is intel wifi 6 AX 201. My wifi is not connecting. Please help me in this regard. Now I have kernel Linux 5.19.0-46-generic.....please solve the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intel AX200 not "claimed" and random purple screening when cursor is in the bottom left corner of the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251424/intel-ax200-not-claimed-and-random-purple-screening-when-cursor-is-in-the-bott)